# Add image to subclassed UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, subclass

I am trying to add a tap gesture from a subclassed UIImageView and then control the tap from the View Controller. I am not getting any compiling errors but "addSubview" is not displaying any image. How can make the UIImageView to be displayed?

If I try to control the tap and pan gestures from the subclassed UIImageVIew I have no problems but I would like to control these functions from the View Controller

Relevant code looks like this.

UIImageView subclass

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
   {
    //self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    previewController = [[PreviewController alloc]init];
    [previewController self];
    [self addSubview:character];
    // Tap Initialization code
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(PreviewController *)self.previewController action:@selector(addCharacter:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

   }
    return self;
}
```

View Controller

```
- (void)addCharacter:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)t
{
    NSLog(@"add character");
    imageNSArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    uiImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"homer.png"];
    CGPoint loc = [t locationInView:self.view];
    character = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:uiImg];
    character.center = loc;
    [imageNSArray addObject:character];
    //Locate the imageNSArray on frameImageView area only.
    [self.view addSubview:character];     
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(panCharacter:)];
    [self.character addGestureRecognizer:pan];
    character.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: You use `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` which may not get called when not loaded from xib. Also, if your `character` is not user interaction enabled, I think the tap gesture recognizer added will never get fired. Maybe you should try to add the recognizer on `character`.

Comment: what is character bounds property? Is it zero on width and height?

Comment: @zetachang I don't think userinteraction enabled should be a problem because when I run that code from the subclass then it displays and can manipulate the uiimageview. While debugging initWithCoder is being called

Comment: @KudoCC I did not set the bounds property. Should I do it before [self.view addSubview:character]; ?

Comment: @Edu You just set the center of the character in your code. You should set the frame of character.

Comment: character.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, uiImg.size.width, uiImg.size.height) ;
    character.center = loc ;

Comment: @KudoCC I am not getting any compile error but still doesn't display. I am thinking the problem might be in CGPoint loc = [t locationInView:self.view];

Comment: @Edu No, I don't mean compile error, I just wan't to make sure the character's size is not zero. If it's size is not zero, please tell me character's frame and self.view's frame.

Comment: self.view frame size is "frame = (0 0; 320 480);"
When I was using this block of code in the subclass it was just "self" and was working perfectly.

Comment: @KudoCC after a double check, yes character's size is 0. which means I am not accessing correctly to the UIImageView subclass?

Comment: @Edu It's size is zero because you didn't set it frame! Try the code `character.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, uiImg.size.width, uiImg.size.height) ; character.center = loc ;`

Comment: @KudoCC with that code it sets the correct frame but it is not displaying. I am almost sure in " CGPoint loc = [t locationInView:self.view];" and "[self.view addSubview:character];" I should be using something else instead of self.view

Comment: You should make sure the character is within the self.view's bounds. That's why I wan't you to show self.view's frame and character'f frame.

Comment: What does the relationship between the view UITapGestureRecognizer is added and self.view in viewcontroller?

Comment: self.view frame is "frame = (0 0; 320 480);" and character is "frame = (0 0; 150 93);"

Answer (score 0):

put a view behind your subclassed imageView. Apply the gestureRecognition to the new View.
You can control your tap gesture from new view. Let me know if i am not clear, or if more info needed.

Comment: should I create this view in the view controller?

Comment: Yes, It should be in same viewController

Comment: I got the idea more or less but I would appreciate if you could be more explicit :).

Comment: I did something like "    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    [newView addSubview:character];" and did not work...

Comment: Ok… you added "Character" as child view for view controller. Similarly add another childView for view controller. Place the newly added view in such a way that it stays behind your customImageView(character). Now apply tapGesturerecognizer to the newly Added view.  Now if you tap on your image, as your image does not have recognizer, tap would be recognized by view that is behind your customImage.  Let me know if more clarification required

Comment: Both should be UIView? or the second one should be UIImageView?

Comment: 2nd one can be UIView.

Comment: I am trying to do what explained but getting same output. could you post dummy code?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is.. .you want to show a image when user taps on screen.
Do following steps:
1. drag & drop a tap gesture recognizer on default view of your view controller.
2. connect (ctrl +) gestureRecognizer with ViewController.m

Take a look at this code. (Just modified your code)

```
- (IBAction)onTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"add character");

    UIImage * uiImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sel.png"];
    CGPoint loc = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    UIImageView * character = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:uiImg];
    character.center = loc;


    [self.view addSubview:character];
}
```

Let me know if this is not what you want…

**Edit**
better go for this code… No need to do above steps.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)onTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"add character");

    UIImage * uiImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sel.png"];
    CGPoint loc = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    UIImageView * character = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:uiImg];
    character.center = loc;

    [self.view addSubview:character];
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid to call the Recognizer from viewDidLoad view controller. That is why I created a subclass of UIImageView. If you see my original code I init with preview controller and then I just call it with "initWithTarget:self.previewController". When I tap it does call the addCharacter method in the preview controller. The problem is that in that case i just can't use addSubview:self.view because I need to access the child's view(UIImageView). I tried initializing with characterImageView = [[CharacterImageView alloc]init]; [characterImageView self]; The approach I am looking is different

Comment: Well than.. good luck with that bro… couldn't understand your question properly… sorry